# Android different visualization on 2.x and 4.x

Tags: android, xml

I'm having some trouble about visualization of items.
On android 2.x  xml fill the screen but in 4.x they cover about 50% of the screen and the other 50% it's all black. I think using fill_parent and wrap_content help me!
How i can standardize it ? Here's the source

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#0058A8" >

       <RelativeLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#0058A8" >



       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/smsnumber"
           android:layout_width="154dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRubrica"
           android:ems="10"
           android:inputType="phone" >

       </EditText>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btnRubrica"
           android:layout_width="119dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:text="@string/phone_book" />

</RelativeLayout>

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/smstext"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="64dp"
           android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="138dp"
        />

   <TimePicker
       android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/start"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/start" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 50% where, which direction? Black is on the right or is it on the bottom (vertical or horizontal problem)?

Answer (score 0):

The root of your layout has to be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0058A8"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- The rest of your layout -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice the `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` properties.

There is no difference in rendering the layout between 2.x and 4.x. The only difference you saw was that the device with 2.x had **smaller resolution** than the 4.x one, there fore on the smaller screen the layout was **filling up all the space**.